# Are there colors women find attractive on men?

Tags: sensation, physical-attraction, sex-differences, attraction

I have heard that men find women dressed in red more attractive (I can confirm this from personal experience as well).

What color or colors do women prefer on men, if any?

Comment: Are you talking about clothes? Any particular clothes? From casual observation, fashions and colours change frequently over time and vary a lot between cultures. Presumably also women differ in their colour preferences. The way that your question is worded it seems to imply (a) that women have such preferences, and (b) that there is something universal over time and place. Thus, while I find the general question interesting, I'm wondering whether your question could be edited to clarify how the question should be constrained by issues of time, culture, type of clothing, etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem difficult to tell what is being asked here.  Are there colors on men that women find "especially" attractive from a biological, evolutionary, or sociological standpoint? I'm very interested in why women find red more attractive. Is there an evolutionary reason? Does it have to do with blood? You made a successful kill and have blood all over you, so women want to mate with you because you're "successful"?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim No, I am not asking specifically about clothing or any particular culture. Given how little information exists on this particular topic, I think narrowing the focus in that way would be silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial report of men finding women more attractive in red or even with a red background on a photo did receive a lot of press.  However, the study has since been done in reverse.  Women tend to find red more attractive on men as well... or even with a red background on their photo.

> Red, rank, and romance in women viewing men.
>   Elliot, Andrew J.; Niesta Kayser, Daniela; Greitemeyer, Tobias; Lichtenfeld, Stephanie; Gramzow, Richard H.; Maier, Markus A.; Liu, Huijun
>   Journal of Experimental Psychology: General, Vol 139(3), Aug 2010, 399-417. doi: 10.1037/a0019689

Comment: ... which begs the question in which culture was it tested? Hopefully you can find the original references.

Comment: @StevenJeuris "This red-potency association appears to be present across cultures
(Oyama, Tanaka, & Chiba, 1962; J. E. Williams, Moreland, &
Underwood, 1970) and age groups (J. E. Williams & McMurtry,
1970)." - http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/xge-139-3-399.pdf